# problem with CS50 Pset7 houses - My database does not collect information

Tags: python, cs50

Please i need help, my import.py code failed to input the required data to the database. I'm trying to add the name details to a dictionary and then print it out in the database. I would also like to know if there is a better way to this. Here is the full code below

```
from sys import argv, exit
from cs50 import SQL
from csv import reader, DictReader

# prompt to make sure user inputs csv file
if len(argv) != 2:
    print("usage: python import.py (csv file)")
    exit(0)

# open that file for sqlite
db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

# read the file using dictreader 
file = open(argv[2], 'r')
csv_file = DictReader(file)


# iterate over csv file in dictread mode
for row in csv_file:
    names = row['name'].split()
    birth = row['birth']
    house = row['house']

#create a dictionary to store names explicitly
if len(names) == 2:
    names_defined = {
        'first name': names[0],
        'middle name': 'None',
        'last name': names[1]
    }
if len(names) == 3:
    names_defined = {
        'first name': names[0],
        'middle name': names[1],
        'last name': names[2]
    }


for i in names_defined:
    first = i['first name']
    middle = i['middle name']
    last = i['last name']

# store the above data in the students database  
db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
first,middle,last,house,birth)
```

Comment: You should narrow down your problem. What is the error that you are getting? Can you elaborate a bit more? The first issue that I see you are opening argv[2] but there are only two arguments' argv[0]: import.py and argv[1]; csv file. I think you should be reading csv file which is argv[1]. Right?

Comment: yes. Thank you very much, the argv[1] was the major problem with the code. I've fixed it and along with some minor ones and now it's working perfectly :)